# Contextual Outlook add-in based on dynamic Regex

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to build a contextual Outlook add-in which is based on Regex. However, the Regex itself isn't known at the time of writing/uploading manifest file. It is obtained from Rest Server and is specific for user.

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/contextual-outlook-add-ins) I've seen only examples and tutorials with fixed regular expressions - provided within manifest.xml. Typical extension point declaration looks like this ([source](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-In-Contextual-Regex/blob/master/contoso-order-number-manifest.xml)):

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="DetectedEntity">
              <Label resid="contextLabel" />
              <SourceLocation resid="detectedEntityURL" />
              <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
                <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" />
                <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="OrderNumber" RegExValue="CO-\d{9}" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext"/>
              </Rule>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

Is there any way to set these rules programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature: contextual addin based on dynamic regex, that you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]